# Unusual Polarity Symbols on Universal Adaptor

Tags: adapter, polarity

The polarity symbols on my universal adapter look a bit different to ones I have seen. Which setting should I use to power the device shown please, top or bottom position for the switch on the adapter?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seem to indicate two different types of connectors - barrel on the right and the "audio jack" type on the left. You need the switch on the upper position.

Answer (score 2):

The "cup and dot" style notation is intended to signify the outer and inner terminals of a barrel connector, respectively.

Your device is expecting the outer connector to be positive, and the inner one negative.  That matches the top right illustration on your power supply.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram should be interpreted as meaning that the switch at the left should be in the lower position to provide a positive power to the centre pin of the output connector or moved to the upper position to provide a negative supply to the centre pin.

The device you are powering needs the switch to be in the upper position.

Answer (score 1):

Your universal adapter likely has multiple connectors. Some will be dc or barrel connectors, the others will be audio, phone or phono connectors. The symbol you see is a mix, trying to depict the polarity of both connectors at the same time. On the left half is the phone plugs while the right half is the standard dc connector symbol.

The symbol on the left shows that the tip of the phone and the center pin of the dc connector is positive, and the sleeve of the phone and the body of the dc connector is negative. The symbol on the right shows the opposite. This is the polarity selection.

Notice that the symbol on the right half matches the symbol on your device. Now you can match the polarity to that symbol.